# TypeScript Using this in function declaration

Tags: angular, typescript, function, constructor, declaration

What does the first parameter mean in this function declaration
 (this: Observable, subscriber: Subscriber) => TeardownLogic;

I came across this declaration in Angular observable, not sure what the first parameter "this: Observable" means in this class  constructor:

```
export declare class Observable<T> implements Subscribable<T> {

    constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic);
   ....}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters

Comment: Btw if it helps, that parameter isn't part of the class constructor, it's the first parameter of the function you provide to the class constructor.